# Style Two Sentences Differently Which Are Part of the same HTML tag

Tags: html, css

If i have a list item with no internal / child html, but which has two sentences of text, is there any way of styling the sentences individually without adding extra html tags?

For instance

Hello Everyone.  How are you?

I appreciate I can add paragraph tags or spans around each line with JS, but wanted to make sure there is no way of doing this with CSS first.

It's dynamically created content in a client's Wordpress site so a CSS solution is preferable.

Thanks

Emily.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, for the browser it's one single string. Hoping someone proves me wrong, though.

Comment: You're right @JonasGiuro . It would be possible if he catches that String with javascript and split it in distinct HTML tags. But it's not what he wants...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing you can get with just CSS is [::first-line](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstline.asp).

Comment: Thanks NeatNit.  It's a shame somebody down-voted the question. But hey-ho.

Comment: I think it's a very good question, one that sounds like there should be an answer to (but as you've seen, there isn't).

Answer (score 1):

There is no pure CSS way to style a single sentence. You will need to place a `span` around the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution for this question is using jS, as in CSS there is no such solution for this kind of query.